# preventDefault and return false are still redirecting user after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am attempting to submit a form, via JQuery's `.ajax` function without redirecting the user on submit. The form itself, and the backend code works correctly. However, I'm having a problem preventing the redirection. I've put a `preventDefault()` in my submit handler, but it still redirects me to the page provided in my form's `action` attribute. I've also tried adding `return false;` at the end of the submit handler, and it still redirects.

My JQuery code looks like this:

```
$("#new_comments").submit(function(e)
{
//  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : $(this).attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        data : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            // Doing things here
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            // Doing things here too
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTML Form:

```
<form name="new_comments" id="new_comments" action="{{ url_for('add_comment_data') }}" method="POST">
    <div id="InputsWrapper">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="comments[]" id="comment_1" value=""/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a>
            <input type="text" name="comments[]" id="comment_2" value=""/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a>
            <input type="text" name="comments[]" id="comment_3" value=""/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="simple-post">Add Comments</button>
</form>
```

The input fields are actually added dynamically, via user input, but this is what the form looks like if the user is input three comments.

How can I prevent the redirection and maintain my existing functionality? In the posted jquery code, it redirect with either the `preventDefault` uncommented or with the `return false` in place.

Comment: its a case of event delegation.

Comment: Your code works fine, does the form exist on page load? If it doesn't then Jai is right - just use this instead: `$(document).on('submit', '#new_comments', function(){`. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Your code appears to work fine. Have you not wrapped the jQuery code in a jQuery load event? e.g. `$(function(){...your code...});` Either that, or not loading jQuery at all, would cause the symptoms mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be working fine. The submits are ignored just fine:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/yPbtz/

```
$(function () {
    $("#new_comments").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // Doing things here
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Doing things here too
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Did you wrap your code in a jQuery document ready event, as shown, or have you failed to include jQuery itself. Either of these will cause the jQuery to be ignored and postbacks to occur.

e.g. if you remove the load event handler, or deselect jQuery from the JSFiddle menu (top left) it will post back and ignore your code.